# Create Pandas dataframe from dictionary - python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert this data structure into a `pandas` dataframe:

```
data = json.dumps(brasil[0]["timelines"]["confirmed"]["timeline"], indent=2)
```

which prints:

```
{
  "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-27T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-28T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-29T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-30T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-01-31T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-02T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-03T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-04T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-05T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-06T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-07T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-08T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-09T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-10T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-11T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-12T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-13T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-14T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-15T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-16T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-17T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-18T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-19T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-20T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-21T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-22T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-23T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-24T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-25T00:00:00Z": 0,
  "2020-02-26T00:00:00Z": 1,
  "2020-02-27T00:00:00Z": 1,
  "2020-02-28T00:00:00Z": 1,
  "2020-02-29T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2020-03-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2020-03-02T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2020-03-03T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2020-03-04T00:00:00Z": 4,
  "2020-03-05T00:00:00Z": 4,
  "2020-03-06T00:00:00Z": 13,
  "2020-03-07T00:00:00Z": 13,
  "2020-03-08T00:00:00Z": 20,
  "2020-03-09T00:00:00Z": 25,
  "2020-03-10T00:00:00Z": 31,
  "2020-03-11T00:00:00Z": 38,
  "2020-03-12T00:00:00Z": 52,
  "2020-03-13T00:00:00Z": 151,
  "2020-03-14T00:00:00Z": 151,
  "2020-03-15T00:00:00Z": 162,
  "2020-03-16T00:00:00Z": 200,
  "2020-03-17T00:00:00Z": 321,
  "2020-03-18T00:00:00Z": 372,
  "2020-03-19T00:00:00Z": 621,
  "2020-03-20T00:00:00Z": 793,
  "2020-03-21T00:00:00Z": 1021,
  "2020-03-22T00:00:00Z": 1546,
  "2020-03-23T00:00:00Z": 1924,
  "2020-03-24T00:00:00Z": 2247,
  "2020-03-25T00:00:00Z": 2554,
  "2020-03-26T00:00:00Z": 2985,
  "2020-03-27T00:00:00Z": 3417,
  "2020-03-28T00:00:00Z": 3904,
  "2020-03-29T00:00:00Z": 4256,
  "2020-03-30T00:00:00Z": 4579,
  "2020-03-31T00:00:00Z": 5717,
  "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z": 6836,
  "2020-04-02T00:00:00Z": 8044
}
```

I've tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data.items()], columns=['date', 'deaths'])
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Are you sure `data` is a dictionary? From the error, it seems to be a string.

Comment: well it prints the dictionary as is above, when I print (data)

Comment: What does `type(data)` return?

Comment: <class 'str'>...

Comment: I get it like so: data = `json.dumps(brasil[0]["timelines"]["confirmed"]["timeline"], indent=2)
`

Comment: Yep, you have a string there and not a dictionary.

Comment: I believe `json.dump(...)` gives you a JSON string. So `data` is a JSON string of dictionary type. You can be lazy and do `pd.DataFrame(eval(data))`. Or you can manually parse the string `data` to dict.

Comment: `eval(data)` did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

With renaming:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')\
       .rename_axis('date')\
       .rename(columns={0:'deaths'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                    date  deaths
0   2020-01-22T00:00:00Z       0
1   2020-01-23T00:00:00Z       0
2   2020-01-24T00:00:00Z       0
3   2020-01-25T00:00:00Z       0
4   2020-01-26T00:00:00Z       0
..                   ...     ...
67  2020-03-29T00:00:00Z    4256
68  2020-03-30T00:00:00Z    4579
69  2020-03-31T00:00:00Z    5717
70  2020-04-01T00:00:00Z    6836
71  2020-04-02T00:00:00Z    8044

[72 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I get `if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`